# Is there a standard term for an associative array in mathematics?

Tags: terminology, propositional-calculus

An associative array in computer science is a set of *keys* and *values* such that each:

- each *key* is unique
- each *key* has a *value*
- each *value* has one or more *keys*

For instance, an associative array describing a shape might contain the following, with the keys in italics.

- *outline*: red
- *fill* : red
- *size*: small
- *sides*: four

Theoretically you could model the associative array as a one-to-many function, but generally an associative array is thought of as holding values rather than manipulating them. It is taken for granted that the key-pair relation exists.

Is there standard term for an associative array in mathematics, such that it is assumed that for any key $a$ there is a value $a'$?

My use case is that I want to use propositional logic to state that following: there exists a key $a$ with value $a'$ in associative array $A$ and a key $b$ with value $b'$ in associative array $B$ such that if $a$ = $b$ then $a'$ = $b'$. I want to say that $A$ and $B$ are [whatever term means associated array] in the descriptive text, and then be able to write something like this, *without needing to state that $a' \in A$ and $b' \in B$ because it is assumed*:

$\exists(a \in A, b \in B)(a = b \rightarrow a'=b')$

Comment: Sounds like a *function* to me.

Comment: More like a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) or [functional relation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Functional_relation).

Comment: Googling even harder, I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316589/mathematical-formal-notation-of-a-dictionary) which while not exactly what I want, does neatly encapsulate the idea of an associative array mathematically. I may be able to use that as a basis for further work.